# Java when i call join i get exception in child and parent thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use join to synchronize my code.  When join is called I get exceptions in both parent and child thread
Exception in thread "thread3"
exception in thread run.

The thread runs in a Ruinable class and stores the thread in public member when the class is created.  The main thread calls the join method on this public member.

the code main thread do

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": waiting for 2 players");

do {
    r=GetClient();
    switch(r)
    {
        case 0: return; // exitvon a very bad error
    }
} while(r==2);// loop if it was a timeout
cMyConnection thread = new cMyConnection("thread3", connection, mPlayerList, mPlayersMessages);
try {
    thread.MyThread.join(); // call join
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the class

```
public class Cconnection   implements Runnable {
    Thread runner;
    ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock;
    Lock read;
    Lock write; 

    boolean StopFlag;
    String header;
    Socket connection;
    ServerSocket  server;
    StringBuffer request;
    OutputStream out;
    InputStream in;
    String ClientMessage;
    public cUsers mPlayerList;  
    public cMessages mPlayersMessages;
    public Thread MyThread;

    public Cconnection(String threadName, Socket connection_in , cUsers PlayerList, cMessages PlayerMessages) {
            connection=connection_in;

            mPlayerList=PlayerList;  
            mPlayersMessages=PlayerMessages;

            MyThread = new Thread(this, threadName); // (1) Create a new thread.

            MyThread.start(); // (2) Start the thread.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My big question is why are you using threads if you are starting a thread and then immediately waiting for it to finish?  Why not just call `cMyConnection.run()` from your main thread?

Also, your code in main references `cMyConnection` but then you list `Cconnection`.  Maybe the problem is in `cMyConnection`?  What does it look like?

Here are some additional comments about your question:

- Your variable name for `cMyConnection` should probably not be `thread`.  It is most likely not a `Thread` class which is what confused @KL.  Maybe `connection` is a better name?
- Whenever you are asking a question on stackoverflow, you should post the exception with the relevant lines from the stack-trace.  This always helps the answerers.
- I would consider adding `start()` and `join()` methods to your `cMyConnection` class.  The idea that in the constructor for a class it forks a thread is a little unusual.  At the very least you should document that in javadocs well.

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet you call "main thread" you create the thread but do not start it. You have to call thread.start() before calling thread.join().

Cheers,

Comment: In this snippet:<br/>`cMyConnection thread = new cMyConnection("thread3", connection, mPlayerList, mPlayersMessages);
try {
    thread.MyThread.join(); // call join
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`<br/> you are missing thread.start()<br>`cMyConnection thread = new cMyConnection("thread3", connection, mPlayerList, mPlayersMessages);` **thread.start();**
`try {
    thread.MyThread.join(); // call join
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`